# windows 10 / raspberry Pi b network sleeps

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-10, mqtt, mosquitto

I am using four Windows 10 computers each accessing Mosquitto, which is installed on a RaspberryPI B. 
I also have 10 ESP8266 nodes connected to mosquitto

monitoring MQTT messages on the computers, two work as expected and two appear to go to sleep for a while, by this i mean no messages are received for some time more usually about 60 seconds but anything up to or above 1000 seconds.

The esp's send alive messages every 15 seconds and all work well. It is these alives that I monitor by counting the messages in a 'burst' and then counting the space between bursts.

When the sleep period is over all of the missed messages are sent to the pc, ie several alive messages from any node will appear in the burst, almost as though the server is saving them up and sending them all together.

**Things that I have already tried:**

- re-installed a new system (jessie) and a new copy of mosquitto on two pi's, each does the same.
- 2) on one of the windows pc's completely wiped the hard drive and re installed a clean copy of windows 10
- disabled the Nagle algorithm in the registry as this can cause networking lag in according to link http://www.fixwindowserrors.biz/blog/disable-nagle-algorithm-in-windows-10#why

I am afraid I have reached the limit of my ability with this problem and desperately need help.

Comment: This sounds more of a networking problem than a programming problem and should probably be asked on Super User rather than Stack Overflow

Comment: @hardillb thanks for the pointer i'll try there